# How to make a toggle button toggled automatically

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtogglebutton

How to make a toggle button toggled automatically when someone types anything in text field??
i am using **java** *Net-beans*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
      jToggleButton1.setSelected(true);
```

and if you are using netbeans go to properties of button and choose selected property mark it checked 
if you want someone to enter the text in the textfield then automatically let the toggle button select use like this

```
    private void jTextField1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
     jToggleButton1.setSelected(true);
    }
```

Comment: you can check if it is selected or not using if(jToggleButton1.isSelected()) {
    jTextField1.setText("BUTTON IS SELECTED");
}

Comment: 1 more minute and i will:P

Comment: Thanks for your positive reply dear so nice of you

Comment: can i use something like if the text field is empty toggle button is off its not empty button is toggle?

Comment: Yes you can let me make another answer for you

Comment: i have made another answer waiting for your reply

Answer (score 3):

Add a listener to the textfield and call toggleButton.setSelected(boolean selected).

Answer (score 3):

```
   if(t.getText().length()==0){

       jToggleButton1.setSelected(true);
   }
   else if(t.getText().length()>0){

      jToggleButton1.setSelected(false);
   }
```

you have to check the length of the text field and then by using the if-else you can select or dis select the  toggle button

Comment: thank you again i would vote +1 but still i need 2 popularity points

Comment: ;) Thanks dear so nice of you

Answer (score -1):

int count=0;

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
    for(int i=0; i<1; i++){count++;}
    count=count;
    System.out.println(count);
    if(count==1){
      System.out.println("open");
      jButton1.setText("open");
     }
    if(count==2){
      System.out.println("close");
      jButton1.setText("close");
    count=0;
    }
```

}